# Can anybody explain me why this output shows Destructor message 6 times?

Tags: c++

[Output of the Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKlpE.png)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex {
private:
    int real;
    int imag;

public:
    Complex(int real, int imag);
    Complex(Complex& c);
    int getreal();
    int getimag();
    void setreal(int real);
    void setimag(int imag);
    Complex operator+(Complex c);
    ~Complex();
};

Complex::Complex(int real = 0, int imag = 0)
{
    this->real = real;
    this->imag = imag;
}

Complex::Complex(Complex& c)
{
    setreal(c.real);
    setimag(c.imag);
}

int Complex::getreal()
{
    return real;
}

int Complex::getimag()
{
    return imag;
}

void Complex::setreal(int real)
{
    this->real = real;
}

void Complex::setimag(int imag)
{
    this->imag = imag;
}

Complex Complex::operator+(Complex c)
{
    Complex temp;
    temp.real = real + c.real;
    temp.imag = imag + c.imag;
    return temp;
}

Complex::~Complex()
{
    cout << "Complex Number Class Destroyed" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Complex c1(5, 10), c2(c1), c3;
    c3 = c1 + c2;
    cout << c3.getreal() << " +i" << c3.getimag() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put output statements into the constructors; that will make things clearer.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but ordinarily, a copy constructor takes its argument by `const&`. So: `Complex(const Complex& c);`. That's not a requirement, but sooner or later you'll run into complications with a copy constructor that takes a non-const reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three destructors are executed for the three objects created in `main()`: `c1`, `c2` and `c3`. Two other objects are created in `operator+`: `c` and `temp`.

Sixth object is created if the compiler does not use [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision). In this case `temp` is copied while returning it from `operator+`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are 6 objects destroyed:
3 of them are you explicitly declared c1,c2,c3 that go out of scope when main ends.
In the operator+ function:

```
Complex Complex::operator+(Complex c)
{
    Complex temp;
...
}
```

This creates a local 'c' and a local 'temp' - both are destroyed when they go out of scope.(2 more destroys)

I suspect your 6th destructor is because a temp object is returned from this function.

There are ways to avoid most of these copies using the 'rule of three' and references.